# Concentric circles with colors in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, swing

ok i am trying to create an archery style target with concentric circles each having different color but the thing is, i am not able to fill each circle with different colors, if i fill one with a particular color, and move on the next, then even the previous circle changes its color to the other circle's color.. How do i fill them up with different colors? here is my code

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

            int fontSize = 20;

            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.drawArc(250, 150, 50, 50, 0, 360);
            g.fillArc(250, 150, 50, 50, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.red);

            g.drawArc(230, 130, 90, 90, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawArc(210, 110, 130, 130, 0, 360);
            g.fillArc(210, 110, 130, 130, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawArc(190, 90, 170, 170, 0, 360);
            g.fillArc(190, 90, 170, 170, 0, 360);

    }
```

Comment: Reverse the order of drawing the circles, you are drawing a larger circle over the smaller circles. And use `fillOval` for ease.

Comment: Custom painting should be done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` not paint(...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JavaFX solution:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class Lab8 extends Application {

    private Pane pane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        pane = new Pane();

        int pwidth = 425;
        int pheight = 425;
        int cx = 210;
        int cy = 210;

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setX(0);
        r.setY(0);
        r.setWidth(pwidth);
        r.setHeight(pheight);
        r.setFill(Color.web("#00ffff"));
        pane.getChildren().add(r);  

        Ellipse c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,205,205);
        c0.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0);

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,185,185);
        c0.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0);     

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,165,165);
        c0.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        c0.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0);     

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,145,145);
        c0.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        c0.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0);                 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,125,125);
        c0.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0); 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,105,105);
        c0.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0); 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,85,85);
        c0.setFill(Color.RED);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0); 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,65,65);
        c0.setFill(Color.RED);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0); 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,45,45);
        c0.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0); 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,25,25);
        c0.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        c0.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0); 

        c0 = new Ellipse(cx,cy,5,5);
        c0.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        c0.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        pane.getChildren().add(c0);         

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,pwidth,pheight);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Target");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
                //stage is closing
                System.out.println("Bye.");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]